# What does signing in to Firebase with SAML resolve with?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, single-sign-on, saml

I have set up my Firebase application to use SAML sign-on, however finding a way to test it has been difficult.

The example code given for signing in with SAML is:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
.then((result) => {
  // User is signed in.
  // Identity provider data available in result.additionalUserInfo.profile,
  // or from the user's ID token obtained via result.user.getIdToken()
  // as an object in the firebase.sign_in_attributes custom claim
  // This is also available via result.user.getIdTokenResult()
  // idTokenResult.claims.firebase.sign_in_attributes.
})
.catch((error) => {
  // Handle error.
});
```

What exactly does the result object look like? I need to get the user's first name, last name, and email. Some IDP's give role information as well, where in the object would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithpopup

So the return is a  `UserCredential`.

You can see all available properties here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#usercredential